# Unity Diagonal Movement Not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my player to move in diagonal directions and this is the code I am using to move in a down diagonal way:

```
 if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0f)
 {
      front45 = true;
      rb.velocity = new Vector3(moveSpeed, -moveSpeed, 0f);
 }
```

however the rigidbody2d wont move in that direction. It will move up, down and from side to side, but never diagonal.

The front45 = true is just for the animator to know when to change animation.

Comment: Is your code successfully entering the if statement? ie. Is the problem with the particular conditions, or the velocity assignment?

Comment: I tried the answer listed and it seems this did the trick. Because I had so many lines of code controlling the character, it could be I went somewhere wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;

if (h != 0 && v != 0)
    front45 = true; //Not sure what this does, so I just left it inside the condition

rb.velocity = new Vector3(h * moveSpeed, v * moveSpeed, 0f);
```

This should work on any direction.

Comment: this is definitely far easier for movement and saves a lot of lines of code

Comment: @lain Blackwood I'm glad I could help